# How can I modify the styles used in html generated from Zeppelin markdown paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to modify a few of the styles used to display markdown paragraphs in my Zeppelin notebooks, like the color of my H2 headings, which use the ".markdown-body h2" style.

Does Zeppelin allow me to specify a css file anywhere? If not, how can I change the styles?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Just link to a stylesheet within a markdown paragraph, and those styles will apply, i.e.

Your markdown will then use the styles in that sheet, within that paragraph.